# Maven fetching the same artifact twice

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I'm using maven to fetch artifacts from a remote repository (aka "Nexus"). for some artifacts, but not all, maven fetches the same artifact twice, once named `SNAPSHOT` and the same artifact again with the `SNAPSHOT` replaced with the actual version and timestamp info.
to me, both seems to be the same `SNAPSHOT` version.

[image]

This makes my life harder while trying to copy the desired artifact to a specified directory. I'm using the maven version range plugin, so I don't know the version its about the fetch directly hence I'm not using the `dependency:copy` plugin.
Currently i'm using `antrun` plugin to copy only a single file with (with `fileset`) sorted by date.

wondering if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

For Maven, if a snapshot version is fetched from the external repository the format is `artifact-${timestamp}-${buildnumber}.jar`
However if it is installed locally by doing `mvn install` then Maven uses the format: `artifact-SNAPSHOT.jar`. So do you build the artifact locally too ?

Comment: My jenkins runs the following goals: clean
install
-U
-B
-e      so yes.

Comment: So if you use dependency:copy along with -U (fetching most updated if any) I think it should work.